# setting file paths for using the "gf" command

Tags: vim, path

I just learned of the gf command. and I am trying to use it but I have questions about how it defines it's paths.

if I am in foo.c which has the header foo.h in the same directory, gf works as expected.  However if from foo.h, I try to get to foo_I.h, which is located in ../includes, it tells me it cannot find the file in the path.  I'm not surprised it doesn't, but is there anyway I can add paths to this list?

Answer (score 1):

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#gf

> Uses the 'path' option as a list of directory names to look for the file.  See the ['path'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27path%27) option for details about relative directories and wildcards.

I.e., `set path+=../includes`